# reshaping a data frame by convert column to index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the following data frame:
i tried to set the batch as an index
but i failed to set the 'avrg' column as common between the indexes and column

```
    avrg    batch   semester
0   1.255000    2003    1
1   3.090000    2003    2
2   3.155000    2003    3
3   3.115000    2004    1
4   3.010000    2004    2
5   2.985000    2004    3
```

i want to set batch in the index and semesters in the columns to get the following:

```
batch   1           2           3
2003    1.255000    3.090000    3.155000
2004    3.115000    3.010000    2.985000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df.pivot(index='batch', columns='semester', values='avrg')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index()

   batch      1     2      3
0   2003  1.255  3.09  3.155
1   2004  3.115  3.01  2.985
```

Or without [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df.pivot(index='batch', columns='semester', values='avrg').rename_axis(None, axis=1)
           1     2      3
batch                    
2003   1.255  3.09  3.155
2004   3.115  3.01  2.985
```